# Specify a clang-format file kept in $HOME

Tags: clang-format

I can use `clang-format` using the following command-

```
clang-format -style=file main.cpp
```

Please note that the `.clang-format` file is kept at the project directory.

**Is there any way to keep `.clang-format` file in $HOME?**

Comment: Hi Ravi, please check my answer below, best.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing clang-fomat on my machine  there wasn't a .clang-format file. After installing via homebrew:

```
brew install clang-format
```

checked again, and I found an empty clang-format file in my HOME directory.

If your clang-format application is already installed, you can place your clang-format file at your HOME directory. That will effect all project which hasn't own a ".clang-format" file.

Best

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS OS by installing clang-format v6. Unfortunately, it is not creating any `.clang-format` file.

Comment: Ravi I'm not sure about ubuntu, I'm working on macOS, brew command is only necessary on macOS. Ubuntu has own solutions I believe, like sudo apt install clang-format, but I'm not sure about the results on that platform.